# Rails Net::HTTP GET format JSON

Tags: ruby, json

There's a site - `https://cdp.cintworks.net/` that brings back a list of URLs either in format `XML` or `JSON`. It brings XML by default, and I've been able to get that to work using this:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://cdp.cintworks.net/")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response = http.request(request)

    puts response.body
```

But I've been struggling to get it to return as `JSON`. I've tried a number of things including:
`request.content_type = 'application/json'`

Any ideas what I should do to force it to return JSON? The documentation I'm following just says it supports JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your `Accept` header instead of your `Content-Type` header--assuming the API doesn't have some other way of negotiating format like a `?format=json` query parameter.

Example:

```
request.initialize_http_header("Accept" => "application/json")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Added example to your answer.